# tclファイルが実行できません

Tags: ubuntu

ubuntu16.04でns2(ns-2.34)を使っています。
サンプルのtclスクリプト(run550.tcl)を実行しようとした結果
以下のようなエラーが表示されました。

```
~/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34/myworkspace/tcl$ ns run550.tcl

wrong # args: should be "source fileName"
    while executing
"source -encoding utf-8 [file join $TclLibDir clock.tcl]"
    (procedure "::tcl::clock::format" line 3)
    invoked from within

"clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y/%m/%d(%a) %p %I:%M:%S}"
    invoked from within
"puts $SimT [clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y/%m/%d(%a) %p %I:%M:%S}]"
    (file "run550.tcl" line 49)
```

実行しているプログラミングはサンプルです。
何がエラーにつながっているのか理解できません
すみませんがご教授お願いします。

追記：
こちらで同様の質問をしています。
https://forums.ubuntulinux.jp/viewtopic.php?id=20199

実験環境の設定等を記述しているrun550.tclのソースのみ貼ります。
　　　これをns-2.34フォルダ内で保存し。実行します
　　　実行コマンド：`~/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34$ ns run550.tcl`

```tcl
#Copyright (c) 1997 Regents of the University of California.
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
# are met:
# 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
# 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
#    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
# 3. All advertising materials mentioning features or use of this software
#    must display the following acknowledgement:
#      This product includes software developed by the Computer Systems
#      Engineering Group at Lawrence Berkeley Laboratory.
# 4. Neither the name of the University nor of the Laboratory may be used
#    to endorse or promote products derived from this software without
#    specific prior written permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE REGENTS AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND
# ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
# IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
# ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE REGENTS OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
# FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
# DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS
# OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
# HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
# LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY
# OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
# SUCH DAMAGE.
#

# Each agent keeps track of what messages it has seen
# and only forwards those which it hasn't seen before.

# Each message is of the form "ID:DATA" where ID is some arbitrary
# message identifier and DATA is the payload.  In order to reduce
# memory usage, the agent stores only the message ID.

# Note that I have not put in any mechanism to expire old message IDs
# from the list of seen messages.  There also isn't any standard mechanism
# for assigning message IDs.  An actual assignment may wish to have the
# students come up with solutions for these problems.

remove-all-packet-headers
add-packet-header Common IP RTP

set SimT [open "Simtime.txt" w]
puts $SimT [clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y/%m/%d(%a) %p %I:%M:%S}]

puts "###############################################"
puts "#   Simulation Start"
puts "###############################################"
# port number
set MESSAGE_PORT 42

# parameters for topology generator
set peer_num 540        ;#送信先の数
set stubNum 10          ;#このidからスタブノード
set max_id 550      ;#ノード最大数
set Snum [expr $stubNum + $peer_num]    ;#送信先 last id
set R_interval 360.0
set ROST_timing 360.0
set finish_time 1800.0
#set group_size 7
#set num_groups 5
#set num_nodes [expr $group_size * $num_groups]

# trial number
set trial_count 30

##################################################
#   only existing idea(ROST):0
#   existing idea + my idea:1
##################################################
set idea 1

# mkdir name:$dir  $dir = ../result/trial_***_$trial_count_$Snum
set dir ../result/trial_
if {$idea == 0} {
    append dir ROST_
} elseif {$idea == 1} {
    append dir myApproach_
} else {
    append dir myIdea_
}
append dir $trial_count
append dir _$Snum
append dir _$finish_time
exec mkdir $dir
# mkdir finish

# make mid flow file
set mid [open "mid-flow" w]
puts $mid [clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y/%m/%d(%a) %p %I:%M:%S}]
puts $mid "Snum:$Snum idea:$idea trial:$trial_count"
close $mid

set ns [new Simulator]

#set f [open flooding.tr w]
#$ns trace-all $f
##set nf [open flooding.nam w]
#$ns namtrace-all $nf

proc ALMstop {id} {
    global a

    $a($id) set ALM -1
}

proc disruptALM {cid} {
    global app n server

    if {[$n($cid) mc-member] == 1 && $cid != $server} {
    $app($cid) ALMdisrupt   
    }
}

proc R_run_stop {} {
    global n app stubNum Snum

    for {set i $stubNum} {$i < $Snum} {incr i} {
        if {[$n($i) mc-member] == 1 } {
            $app($i) R_notrun
        }
    }
}

# log statics
proc fileoutput {} {
    global app stubNum Snum dir n server serverdegree

    # logfile name $dir = ../result/trial_***_$trial_count_$Snum/treestate
    append dir /treestate

    set TS [open "$dir" w]
    puts $TS "server id:$server\tdegree:$serverdegree"
    puts $TS "id root start_t stop_t total_recv SD_recv descenNum degree u_degree f_degree depth leaf parent_id child_id"
    close $TS

    for {set i $stubNum} {$i < $Snum} {incr i} {
        if {[$n($i) mc-member] == 1 } {
            $app($i) treestate $dir
        }
    }
}

# finish proc
proc finish {} {
        global ns f nf paraS at_f lt_f bw_f SimT

        puts ""
     puts "(Otcl)finish!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
     puts ""
     puts $SimT [clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y/%m/%d(%a) %p %I:%M:%S}]

        $ns flush-trace
        #close $f
        #close $nf
        close $paraS
        close $at_f
        close $lt_f
        close $bw_f
        close $SimT

        fileoutput

        puts "running nam..."
        #exec nam flooding.nam &
        exit 0
}

# descendant manage
proc descendant {} {
    global app stubNum Snum n

    for {set i $stubNum} {$i < $Snum} {incr i} {
        if {[$n($i) mc-member] == 1 } {
            $n($i) descendantnum_reset
        }
    }
    for {set i $stubNum} {$i < $Snum} {incr i} {
        if {[$n($i) mc-member] == 1 } {
            $app($i) descendant
        }
    }
}

# rejoin proc
proc ALM_rejoin {Fid} {
    global ns a

    puts ""
    puts "(Otcl)ALM Rejoining\tFid = $Fid"
    puts ""

    set t [$ns now]

    set mid [open "mid_flow" a]
    puts $mid "$t $Fid rejoing"
    close $mid

    $a($Fid) set parent_Element {}
    $a($Fid) set messages_seen {}
    $a($Fid) set count 0
    $a($Fid) set flooding_timeout -1
    $a($Fid) set flooding_count -1
    $a($Fid) send_message 9 -1 {ALM search} $Fid
    $ns at [expr $t+1.0] "$a($Fid) time_manegement $Fid [expr $t+0.10]"
    after 1200
    #exit 0
}

##############################################
#   only existing idea(ROST):0
#   existing idea + my idea:1
##############################################
#set idea 0
# myidea proc
proc MYIDEA {} {
    global ns app n idea stubNum Snum server

    puts ""
    puts "(Otcl)MY IDEA start"
    puts ""

    set MY 0

    for {set i $stubNum} {$i <= $Snum} {incr i} {
        if {[$n($i) mc-member] == 1 && $i != $server} {
        if {[$app($i) L_run] == 1} {
            $ns at [expr $now+3.0] "MYIDEA"
            set MY 1
            break;
        }}
    }
    if {$MY == 0} {
    for {set i $stubNum} {$i <= $Snum} {incr i} {
        if {[$n($i) mc-member] == 1 && $i != $server} {
            $app($i) MYIDEA_start
        }
    }
    }
}
# ROST proc
proc ROST {} {
    global ns app n idea stubNum Snum R_interval server

    puts ""
    puts "(Otcl)ROST start"
    puts ""

    set t $R_interval
    set now [$ns now]
    set L 0

    for {set i $stubNum} {$i < $Snum} {incr i} {
        if {[$n($i) mc-member] == 1 && $i != $server} {
        if {[$app($i) L_run] == 1} {
            $ns at [expr $now+3.0] "ROST"
            set L 1
            break;
        }}
    }

    if {$L == 0} {
    for {set i $stubNum} {$i < $Snum} {incr i} {
        if {[$n($i) mc-member] == 1 && $i != $server} {
            $app($i) ROST_start $idea
        }
    }
        $ns at [expr $now+$t] "ROST"
    }
}

# class member
source flooding_class.tcl

## Topology Generator
puts "node create start"
for {set i 0} {$i <= $Snum} {incr i} {
    #puts -nonewline "$i..."; flush stdout
    set n($i) [$ns node]
}
puts "node create finish"

$n($Snum) shape "hexagon"

# parameter
source linkdelay.tcl ;#bounded-random link delay
source ../link/$Snum.tcl    ;#physical link
set paraS [open "../para/$Snum/server$Snum-$trial_count.txt" r]
set at_f [open "../para/$Snum/arrival$Snum-$trial_count.txt" r]
set lt_f [open "../para/$Snum/leave$Snum-$trial_count.txt" r]
set bw_f [open "../para/$Snum/degree$Snum-$trial_count.txt" r]


#サーバー決定 - server dicision
gets $paraS serverID
set server $serverID
set serverdegree 100
#puts "server\t$server"

$n($server) shape "box"

# attach a new Agent/MessagePassing/Flooding to each node on port $MESSAGE_PORT, Agent_id, degree, server_id
for {set i 0} {$i < $Snum} {incr i} {
    set a($i) [new Agent/MessagePassing/Flooding]
    $n($i) attach  $a($i) $MESSAGE_PORT
    $a($i) set messages_seen {}
    $a($i) setid $i
    if {$i >= $stubNum && $i != $Snum} {
     gets $bw_f degree_num
     gets $lt_f stop_time
     #puts "$i:degree_num \t $degree_num"
           if {$i != $server} {
        $a($i) set degree $degree_num
        $a($i) set stoptime $stop_time
       } elseif {$i == $server} {
           $a($i) set degree $serverdegree
           }
    } elseif {$i == $Snum} {
        $a($i) set degree 0
     }
    #$a($i) puts "id:$i , degree:$degree"
    $a($i) set root $server
}

set tree [new ALMtree]
$tree tracefile $dir

# logfile name $dir = ../result/trial_***_$trial_count/descendant
set DL [open "$dir/descendant" w]
puts $DL "server id:$server\tdegree:$serverdegree"
puts $DL "id stop_t descenNum"
close $DL

#$ns duplex-link $n($Snum) $n($server) $linkBW [tt] DropTail

$ns at $ROST_timing "ROST"

$a($server) set ALM_ 1
set app($server) [new ALMApp 1 -1 $serverdegree $n($server) $tree]
$app($server) start

#$ns at 0.0 "$a($Snum) send_message 900 -1 {ALM search} $Snum"
#$ns at 0.1 "$a($Snum) time_manegement $Snum 0.0"
#set app($Snum) [new ALMApp -1 $server 0 $n($Snum) $tree]
#$app($Snum) start

set fID $stubNum
# now set up some events
for {set i $stubNum} {$i < $Snum} {incr i} {
 gets $at_f arrival_time
 $a($i) set AT $arrival_time
# if {$i == $server || $i < 41}
  if {$i != $server} {
    puts "$i:arrivaltime \t $arrival_time"
    $ns at $arrival_time "$a($i) send_message 9 $fID {ALM search} $i"
    $ns at [expr $arrival_time+1.0] "$a($i) time_manegement $i [expr $arrival_time+1.0]"
    incr fID
 }
}

$ns at $finish_time "finish"

$ns run
```

Comment: ns-allinone-2.34 に含まれる tcl のバージョンは 8.4.18 で、source コマンドの `-encoding` オプションは利用できません。どうやら、バージョン 8.5 で追加されたオプションの様です。

Comment: metropolisさん、ありがとうございます^-^。しかしサンプルソースは、ns-2.34で起動確認済みのソースなので、このようなエラーが出るというのはどういった理由なのでしょうか。tclのバージョンを8.5にしてみます。

Comment: 過去にns-2.35を同様のubuntuにインストールしたのですが、それが何か関係している可能性はありますか

Comment: マルチポスト - https://forums.ubuntulinux.jp/viewtopic.php?id=20199

Comment: サンプルであっても実行したファイル(run550.tcl)の中身を質問文に含めるか、配布元のURLなどを提示して第三者が中身を確認できるようにしてもらうと回答も付きやすくなるんじゃないかと思います。

Comment: おそらく別のC++のファイルを含めての再コンパイルが上手くいっていないからのようです。。。

Answer (score 0):

こちらの問題はC++のファイルを含めてのns2の再コンパイルがうまくできていないためのエラーと判断しました。そのため、この質問を終了します。